# What is the most appropriate way to copy data from SQL server to Azure synapses analytics

Tags: azure, polybase, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

After reading the web I have two options for this

1. Copy data using ADF from SQL server to Azure synapses analytics.
2. Copy data to blob storage and from there copy data using external tables to the Azure synapses analytics.

What is the best way out of these two?

Is  "Copy data to blob storage from there copy data using ADF to the Azure synapses analytics" can be considered as another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy data from SQL server to Azure synapses analytics need configure Staging storage account:
[image]

I don't think you need options 2.

Hope this helps.